# Series expansion - $\omega^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I already know Taylor and McLaurin expansions, but there is one which is grinding my gears: the power series. I conjecturate there must be a way to decompose any function into an infinite vector space, but for now I am happy with the power series. In my control book there is this serie:

$(j\omega\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A})^{-1} = \frac{\mathbf{I}}{j\omega} - \frac{\mathbf{A}}{\omega^2} + \frac{\mathbf{A}^2}{j\omega^3} + ...$

It might (or not) be right, do not take it for granted. I am here to find where does it comes from and if it even its final form (I mean, if there is a more general theory in background).

So long and thanks for all the fish.

Comment: This is called [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus). What they are doing is evaluating $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...$ at $\frac{\mathbf{A}}{j\omega}$ and multiplying by $\frac{1}{j\omega}$. It looks like the second ${}-{}$ should be a ${}+{}$.

Comment: I am afraid the second signal is right, but not the next ones. But thanks for explaining. I think i do not need to jump into such formalism.

Comment: Ah, $j$ is the imaginary unit!. They replaced $j^2=-1$.

Comment: Precisely. Then, the third term must have - signal as well.